# Chrome extension Access-Control-Allow-Origin with permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I noticed today  chrome extension started to fire an error to all requests

"' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

I'm using  permissions  in manifest  and it was working just fine

but today it won't working no matter how many permissions I add

is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: after some research i found a solution. See this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666195/cors-issue-after-latest-chrome-85-update/63735658#63735658